# Previous Year row in measurement, DAX formula

Tags: excel, row, powerpivot, dax

I have the following table:

Year test is the list of previous year:

```
=SUMX(Datasrc;Datasrc[Year]-1)
```

How do I get something similar for "`Calculated field 1`"? In other words, I want to get the previous "`Price/kg`" so it match column C, "`Year test`".

I have tried with the formula from [Find rows relative to current row's value in excel (DAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973744/find-rows-relative-to-current-rows-value-in-excel-dax):

```
=SUMX(
        FILTER(Datasrc; EARLIER([Year]) = [Year] + 1 );
        Datasrc[C_Total Asset Per Share]
)
```

But only get: "Calculation error in measure 'Datasrc'[Calculated field 2]: EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist."

The column A is `[Year]`

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't entirely clear: you just want to see the previous year's value for a given measure? Like Sales 2015 vs. Sales 2014?

Comment: Sorry, I see there are some misstake in my text :(

**Correct is:**
How do I get something similar for "`Calculated field 1`"? In other words, I want to get the "`C_Total Asset Per Share`" in Column D to "jump" one row upward so B26 value will be at D25 and B25 will be at D24.

see link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DCvoI.png

Thanks in advance :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAX has time intelligence functions built in, so it's fairly easy to do what you'd like using the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` function.

First you need a date table joined to your fact table. Then just do

```
CALCULATE ( [Base Measure], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DateTable[Date]) )
```

Comment: Thanks worked out very well.
I needed to adjust my raw data to excel date, i.e. 2015-01-01 and then I could use it properly in my calculations :)!